# How to remove a specific notification forever using react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification, react-native-notifications

I am currently using the `react-native-push-notification` library to schedule and receive notifications in my React Native app. I am able to cancel a scheduled notification using the cancelLocalNotification method, but this only cancels the notification for 24 hours. I want to find a way to remove a specific notification forever, so it will not be rescheduled.

I have tried using the following code to cancel a notification by its ID, but it only cancels it for 24 hours:

```
const onCancelNotification = async (id: string) => {
    // Get a list of all scheduled notifications
    PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications((notifications) => {
      // Iterate through the list of notifications
      notifications.forEach((notification) => {
        // Check if the notification is the one you want to cancel
        if (notification.id.indexOf(id) === 0) {
          // Cancel the notification
          PushNotification.cancelLocalNotification(notification.id);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet demonstrates a workaround for removing a specific scheduled local notification in React Native. The function `onRemoveNotification` takes in an `id` parameter, which is used to identify the specific notification that needs to be removed.

It's important to note that there is no direct method for removing a specific scheduled local notification in React Native. This code provides a workaround that can be used, but it's important to be aware that it relies on scheduling a notification with an earlier date and setting the `repeatType` to undefined.

Please note that this code is not a perfect solution and could have side effects on the app.

```
const onRemoveNotification = async (id: string) => {
  // Get a list of all scheduled notifications
  PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications((notifications) => {
    // Iterate through the list of notifications
    notifications.forEach((notification) => {
      // Check if the notification is the one you want to cancel
      if (notification.data.notificationId?.indexOf(id) === 0) {
        // Create a new date one day earlier than the current scheduled date
        const earlyDate = moment(notification.date).add(-1, "day").toDate();
        // remove the notification
        // schedule the notification with an earlier date and repeat type undefined
        // this will effectively "remove" the notification
        // since it will not be displayed
        PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
          id: notification.id,
          title: notification.title,
          message: notification.message,
          repeatType: undefined,
          date: earlyDate,
        });
        // cancel the previous scheduled notification
        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotification(notification.id);
      }
    });
  });
};
```